# Removing duplicate records from relational db table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a database table with three columns. Id, user_id, book_id. In this table, there are some duplicates. a user_id should only have one record of a book_id, but in some cases, a user_id has several book_ids. There are a couple of million records already and I'm wondering how to remove any duplicates.

Comment: so, what is the basis for the records to be removed? randomly as long as it leaves one record for each user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following.

SQL SERVER

```
WITH ORDERED AS
(
    SELECT id
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] , [book_id] ORDER BY id ASC) AS rn
    FROM
    tableName
)
delete from tableName
where id in ( select id from ORDERED where rn != 1)
```

MYSQL

```
delete from tableName
where id not in( 
    select MIN(id)from tableName    
    group by user_id, book_id
)
```

**Edited as per comments - In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part**

This will solve the issue.

```
delete from tableName
where id not in( 
    select temp.temp_id from (
        select MIN(id) as temp_id from tableName    
        group by user_id, book_id
    ) as temp
)
```

This will keep only one combination of (user_id, book_id)

Comment: you can move it to subquery easily.

Comment: and how about `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: my bad, working in sql server for quite long, just missed question is for mysql.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for exactly, but I'm getting this error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDERED AS
(
    SELECT id
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id' at line 1

Comment: @William, yeah the query I posted was for Sql Server not MySql. Edited my answer, check now.

Comment: I'm getting: You can't specify target table '' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this statement below, it will delete all duplicate records of `user_ID` and leaving only the greatest `ID` for each `user_ID`

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) b ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
                a.ID = b.max_ID
WHERE   b.max_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24209/6)

Comment: `JOIN` performs far more better than `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query will allow you to remove duplicates:

```
DELETE bl1 FROM book_log bl1
JOIN book_log bl2
ON (
    bl1.id > bl2.id AND
    bl1.user_id = bl2.user_id AND
    bl1.book_id = bl2.book_id
);
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecd54/2)